# классификация анимации Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Я пытаюсь классифицировать анамацию Flutter. Посмотрите и подскажите, возможно где-то что-то не так и какими классами еще можно дополнить. Спасибо.

**1) Code-based animation / Анимация на основе кода**
-easiest / самый легкий
--Implicit animation / неявная анимация
---Built-in implicit animation / встроенная неявная анимация

- AnimatedFoo
- AnimatedAlign
- AnimatedContainer
- AnimatedDefaultTextStyle
- AnimatedOpacity
- AnimatedPadding
- AnimatedPhysicalModel
- AnimatedPositioned
- AnimatedPositionedDirectional
- AnimatedSize

---Custom implicit animation / пользовательская неявная анимация

- TweenAnimationBuilder

-harder / тяжелый
--Explicit animation / явная анимация
---Built-in explicit animation / встроенная явная анимация

- FooTransition

---Custom explicit animation / пользовательская явная анимация

- AnimatedWidget
- AnimatedBuilder

**2) Drawing-based animation / Анимация на основе рисования**
-hardest / тяжелейший

- CustomPainter

Comment: Для чего вы это делаете, если это есть в [документации](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation)?

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Я просмотерел несколько видео из документации. В первом видео, девушка пыталась как-то разложить все по полочкам. Это на основании ее фильма я и пытаюсь классифицировать, что бы было понятно. В данной документации я точных определений не нашел.